# Is it possible to constantly update TextView text without allocating additional memory?

Tags: android, textview

I have implemented an elapsed time counter that uses a `TextView` to display elapsed time down to hundredths of a second.  On each update, my current implementation reads the elapsed time, allocates a new `String` formatted to be user-readable, and updates the `TextView` text with this `String`.

It seems like a huge waste of memory that each `String` is used only once for a tiny fraction of a second and then quickly discarded forever.  Is there a way to continuously update the `TextView` text without allocating additional memory for a new `String` each time?

Here is the method I am currently using to format my text:

```
public static String formatTime(long time) {
    int minute = (int) (time / 60000);
    int second = (int) (time / 1000) % 60;
    int hundredth = (int) (time / 10) % 100;
    return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", minute, second, hundredth);
}
```

The calling function calculates the elapsed time, calls this function, and then immediately calls `setText(String)` on the `TextView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are doing a good job. If you really want to do avoid allocation string try [StringBuffer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuffer.html). But then you have to let go the the `format` api and do everything urself which may not be as performing as you think. Also your current implementation makes it thread safe.

Comment: Thanks, after some research I've decided the `String.format()` function is too helpful to get rid of.  I will leave it as is.

Answer (score 1):

On going through the documentation on the setText() method, I noticed that the method signature is..

```
setText(CharSequence text)
```

On digging further I discovered that StringBuilder also implements the CharSequence interface.

So I guess a solution would be to `start using StringBuilder instead of the String` object.

The only concern left for me is the String.format() method can no longer be used, so we have to start using the Formatter class.

more info can be found here [Formatter Class](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-tiger04024/index.html).

I hope it helps...